# How do I occupy a textbox with this JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am currently using JSON, AJAX, JQuery, and javascript. My JSON look like this

```
[{[{
    "eventName":"Event Name",
    "operationgDivision":"Operating Division",
    "startDate":"05/14/2014",
    "endDate":"05/19/2014",
    "siteStartDate":"05/14/2014",
    "siteEndDate":"05/19/2014",
    "relatedEventName":"Related Event Name",
    "relatedEventStartDate":"05/14/2014",
    "relatedEventEndDate":"05/19/2014",
    "objective":"Objective Info",
    "targetAudience":"Target Audience",
    "howToReachTargetAudience":"How to reach target audience",
    "singleMessageToCommunicate":"Single message to communicate",
    "challengesToConsider":"Challenge to consider",
    "creativeConsideration":"Creative Consideration",
    "creativeConsiderationAttachement":"",
    "competitiveConsideration":"Competitive Consideration",
    "competitiveConsiderationAttachement":"",
    "pOSStartDate":"05/15/2014",
    "pOSEndDate":"05/19/2014",
    "ID":1
}]
```

I am currently trying to set the value of the my txtEventName textbox to the eventName data that is within the array in my callback.js file, but I'm having difficulty. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's invalid JSON fyi - You have an array inside an object without a key property

Comment: what does "having difficulty" mean exactly...?

Comment: Most examples have a Parent header section for each part of the data, however; mine does not.

Comment: @MasterP -- And that's invalid

Comment: @tymeJV is correct.  you can see the problem for yourself [here](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

Comment: When I do process it, it returns a valid status. I did think I was missing the "Parent header" (Key). I just have to figure out how to insert it into the data

Comment: {**myArray**:[{ /*obj*/ }, { /*obj*/ }, { /*obj*/ }]}